# Guice 3 in Struts2

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, guice, jsr330

I'm trying to integrate `Guice 3` into my `Struts` application.
This is what I did :
Interface:

```
public interface PersonDAO{
    void addPerson(String username);
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Singleton
public Class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{
    void addPerson(String username){
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

I created the `Guice` module :

```
public class ServiceInjector extends AbstractModule {    
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
      bind(PersonDAO.class).to(PersonDAOImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Then I use it like this in my `Action`:

```
@Inject
private PersonDAO personDAO;
```

The problem is that `personDAO` is always null.

Question : **how can I properly integrate `Guice` to my application** ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried, but:

1. include in your project a Struts2 plugin written to interact with Guice (the [Guice-Struts2 plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-struts2)); 
   for example, with Guice 4 and Maven, in your pom.xml it would be:

   ```xml
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
       <artifactId>guice-struts2</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Then, in your struts.xml, specify that the **ObjectFactory** is `guice`:

   ```xml
   <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="guice" />
   ```

It should be enough.